# Why javascript leaves one blank array but only in some cases

Tags: javascript, arrays

my code goes through quite a large number of arrays where everything is sorted so that it is in the right place. It flies 3 times through the input data to sort everything well, which causes empty arrays to appear. I try to delete them with the following code, but in some cases the code leaves me 1 empty array

The following code works correctly in most cases, but in some cases 1 array is left undeleted

```
chartTypeData.forEach((item: any, index: any) => {
        if (item.length === 0) {
            chartTypeData.splice(index, 1);
        }
});
```

Full code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < chartType.length; i++) {
        const chartItem = chartsData?.product?.data[0].attributes.product_charts.data;
        for (let j = 0; j < chartCategory.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < country.length; k++) {
                chartTypeData.push(
                    chartItem.filter((item: any) => {
                        return (
                            item.attributes.type === chartType[i] &&
                            item.attributes.chartCategory === chartCategory[j] &&
                            item.attributes.country === country[k]
                        );
                    })
                );
            }

            chartTypeData[i].sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                return new Date(a.attributes.date).getTime() - new Date(b.attributes.date).getTime();
            });
        }
    }

    chartTypeData.forEach((item: any, index: any) => {
        if (item.length === 0) {
            chartTypeData.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
```